# Nant run exec task under different user

Tags: nant

It is possible to run Exec task with different domain and user ?

I need to restart iis on 10 load balancers , can this be achieved with Nant exe task ?

For now I have script like

```
<exec programm='iisreset'>
  <arg line='${balancer}'/>
  <arg line='/restart' />

 </exec>
```

This is working on Integration environment (Since the same domain) , and on test it fails with Acces Denied..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the command `runas` in you `exec` call and use the the `/netonly` argument for remote access to your balancers.

I guess this could look something like this:

```
<exec program="runas">
  <arg line="/netonly" />
  <arg line="${'/user:' + domain + '\' + username}" />
  <arg line="${'&quot;iisreset ' + balancer + ' /restart&quot;'}" />
</exec>
```

This could work for you but I am not sure how you are going to give him the password automatically. You could run `runas` with `/savecred` in your cmd once though. But be careful about saving your passwords...

**Note that I could not test this as I don't have the required environment to do so.**

Source: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true